# Blogger: How can I add a "Code" paragraph type?

Tags: blogger, formatting

Blogger paragraph types are Normal, Heading, Subheading, and Minor Heading.  How can I add a Code type that will set a small, bold, fixed-width font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a Code style to your template   (Template / Customize / Advanced / CSS).

But you cannot add the value to the drop-down menu in the post editor's Compose mode.   Instead, to use the style you need to switch to HTML mode, and apply it manually with something like

```
<div class="yourClassName"> your paragraph of code </div>
```